# Add strings with tags as HTML using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have a html table data formatted as a string I'd like to add a HTML row.

Let's say I have a row tag `tag` in BeautifulSoup.

```
<tr>
</tr>
```

I want to add the following data to the row which is formatted as a string (including the inner tags themselves)

```
<td><a href="www.example.com">A</a>\</td><td>A1<time>(3)</time>, A2<time>(4)</time>, A3<time>(8)</time></td>
```

Is there an easy way to do this through BeautifulSoup or otherwise (for example, I could convert my document to a string, but I would make it harder to find the tag I need to edit). I'm not sure If I have to add those inner tags manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `tag.append`:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = "<tr></tr>"
my_string = r'<td><a href="www.example.com">A</a>\</td><td>A1<time>(3)</time>, A2<time>(4)</time>, A3<time>(8)</time></td>'


soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
soup.find("tr").append(BeautifulSoup(my_string, "html.parser"))

print(soup)
```

Prints:

```html
<tr><td><a href="www.example.com">A</a>\</td><td>A1<time>(3)</time>, A2<time>(4)</time>, A3<time>(8)</time></td></tr>
```